# How to achive `npm run build`, change 'config.js', then run `npm run build`

Tags: node.js, webpack, npm-scripts

I have a project, and need to build accroding to a `config.js` file,

eg:  I  hava a file

`config.js`

```
module.exports = {
   themeColor: 'red'
}
```

how can i do
the following things?

1. excute `npm run build`
2. change `config.js` `themeColor` to `yellow`
3. excute `npm run build`
4. ....

How could i write a program to build multi  distributions ?